# Upgrading from jdk17 to jdk21 caused increased cpu usage during GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-21

I have spring boot apps running on k8s.

After upgrading a app from jdk17 og jdk21 in production, we see a increased cpu usage during GC causing pod scalling.

The initial k8s request.limit was set to 200m which is enough to handle the app workload and GC on jdk 17.

After upgrade to jdk 21 we had to raise the request.limit to 300m so there where enough cpu headroom for GC without causing pod scaling.

The pod is started using:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx201770K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=105429K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
```

So using the default GC.

I wondering if this is expected behaviour since there has been a lot of improvements in jdk 21 regarding GC.

Second if there is any better GC settings on jdk21 that could reduce cpu spikes eg. Parallel GC

[image: gc]
[image: gc-cpu]

Comment: There is insufficient information for anyone (apart from you) to understand what is actually going on.

Comment: There are lot of different numbers people like to label “memory usage” and this particular example does not seem to show heap memory usage, as the graph is atypical for that. Further, the spikes in the CPU usage do not even align to the drops in memory usage, so the conclusion that they are due to garbage collected is not backed by anything shown here.